# Divergence not defined

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differentiation, mathematics, singularities, dirac-delta-distributions

I’m currently working on the practice problems in Introduction to Electrodynamics by Griffiths. I got confused by the solution to this problem.

[image]

What does “ill-defined divergence” even mean? I understand how and when to use delta function, but I don’t understand how divergence is not defined.

Comment: is the delta-function well defined at the origin?

Comment: I suggest that you evaluate the divergence of the ${\bf v}$ field. Is there any delta function? And what is the value of the divergence at the origin?

Comment: @GiorgioP I think I got it. When $n<-2$, there’s a zero in the denominator if we want to calculate the divergence at the origin

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use

$$
\nabla \cdot (\psi \vec{a}) = \vec{a} \cdot \nabla \psi + \psi \nabla \cdot \vec{a}
$$

to see what's happened for $n \lt -2$.

$$\begin{align*}
\nabla \cdot (r^{-3} \hat{r})
&= \left( \frac{1}{r^2} \hat{r} \right)
  \cdot \nabla \frac{1}{r}
  + \frac{1}{r} \nabla \cdot \frac{1}{r^2} \hat{r} \\
&= - \frac{1}{r^4}
  + \frac{1}{r} \nabla \cdot \frac{1}{r^2} \hat{r}
  && \left( \nabla \frac{1}{r} = - \frac{1}{r^2} \right) \\
&= - \frac{1}{r^4}
  + \frac{4 \pi}{r} \delta^3(\vec{r})
\end{align*}$$

When $r$ toward $0$ (below misuses the delta function, delta function is meaning less outside of integral),

$$\begin{align*}
\nabla \cdot (r^{-3} \hat{r})
&= - \frac{1}{r^4}
  + \frac{4 \pi}{r} \delta^3(\vec{r}) \\
&= -\infty + \infty \cdot \infty
\end{align*}$$

We can not assign a meaningful value to $\nabla \cdot (r^{-3} \hat{r})$, so it is called "ill-defined".